# How can I get a database out of a Windows 7 MySQL Database stored on a backup hard drive?

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I had a catastrophic drive failure on my development machine. Fortunately I have a backup of everything.

I just installed WAMP for the first time, and it seems to be working in windows 7 x64 (after the fresh install on a new drive). Now I need to get access to the databases I had stored on the backup drive..I don't have .sql dump files.

Does anyone know how I can get a database export from the MySQL folder I have on my backup drive?

Thanks!

Comment: I would prefer not to copy directories, and instead pull out a .sql dump file. Is this possible?

Comment: No it is not, as you need some SQL engine that can read data in database files in order to produce SQL statements. Even official MySQL's `mysqldump` requires up-and-running MySQL server.

Comment: Do not hesitate with copying. I successfully transfered databases from Windows MySQL 5.1 to Mac OS X MySQL 5.1 (both MyISAM and InnoDB formats) this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple copy of files and folders located in MySQL data directory should do the trick (as long as MySQL versions are the same).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure wheteher this will work . Just replace the your mysql folder in wamp installation directory with yours. Remember to keep back up before replacing